# How to change R version in Rstudio inside a conda environment in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, anaconda, rstudio, conda

I have R 4.3 and Rstudio installed in the base system, and an older version of R (4.2.3) in a conda environment.

The command `which R` returns the directory of the R installed in the environment:

> /home/user/miniconda3/envs/anndata2ri_pip/bin/R

and R=4.2.3 is loaded if I call R in the terminal.

If I call rstudio, I have R=4.3. even after
`export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R="/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/anndata2ri_pip/bin/R"`
I still get the version installed in base system, and the following warning

> WARNING: R shared object (/home/user/miniconda3/envs/anndata2ri_pip/lib/R/lib/libR.so) failed load test with error:
> Linux may have loaded a different libR.so than requested. This can result in "package was built under R version X.Y.Z" user warnings and R_HOME/R version mismatches.
> R_HOME: /home/user/miniconda3/envs/anndata2ri_pip/lib/R
> R Version: 4.3.0. Please contact your system administrator to correct this libR.so install.

The command `export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R` works, because I tried to set a random folder, and Rstudio fails with a "R not installed" message.

I am aware of [the main Rstudio support page on the topic](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-the-RStudio-Desktop-IDE), but it didn't really help.

Thanks!

Comment: There's [a bug in recent RStudio builds for Ubuntu](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12508) that prevents loading Conda environments. Please add your voice to the Issue as that will help convey to the developers that this is important to users.

Comment: I just filed an identical bug report. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13184