# Why is there an Graphics API version mismatch error when I try to graph?

Tags: r, ubuntu, anaconda, rstudio, updates

After updating R to version 4.3.0, I have lost all plotting capabilities, causing my machine to output error messages such as: `Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (Error in grDevices: Graphics API version mismatch)`. This specifically has effected my plotting functions.

I am not sure what to do to fix this problem as I have uninstalled all associated packages, uninstalled and reinstalled R to my desktop. Additionally, I get the error message:
`Linux may have loaded a different libR.so than requested. This can result in "package was built under R version X.Y.Z" user warnings and R_HOME/R version mismatches.`

Any help is appreciated!

I tried to uninstall and reinstall R/all associated packages. Nothing changed.

Comment: This is *usually* from a package mismatch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68753250/getting-the-error-graphics-api-version-mismatch  , but in your case it seems to be more likely to be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76102591/how-to-change-r-version-in-rstudio-inside-a-conda-environment-in-ubuntu .  Are you running under conda?